# How to auto enable Search bar in UISearchController when that page appear?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

This is code about my search in the app.

```
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController:  nil)
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.delegate = self
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.gray
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

I want to my search bar auto active when the page appear?

Dose anyone has ideas to do that? You can look on my image to make clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add to viewWillAppear `self.searchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer